# In the solution below how is (cosC+3√sinC)= 2sin(π6+C)?

Tags: geometry

You can use the Law of cosine and the area formula of a triangle to solve this problem. Suppose the three angles are A,B,C opposite to the sides a,b,c, respectively. Then
c2=a2+b2−2abcosC,S=12absinC
and hence
a2+b2+c2−4S3√==≥=≥2[a2+b2−ab(cosC+3√sinC)]2[a2+b2−2absin(π6+C)]2(a2+b2−2ab)2(a−b)20
since sin(π6+C)≤1. The equal sign holds iff a=b and sin(π6+C)=1, which implies that a=b,C=π3 or a=b=c.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, edit your post and use MathJax to typeset your formulas; as it's currently written, the question is barely readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:
Use $$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$

Hope you know or can derive the values of $\displaystyle\sin\frac\pi6,\cos\frac\pi6$

Comment: How were you able to figure out what the OP was trying to say? It’s incomprehensible!

Comment: @Argument, I have followed the title